# Remove/Insert code at compile time without duplication in C++

Tags: c++, templates

I have a template class that is taking in a couple of types. One type is there just to determine policies. That class determines how a function may work in certain cases.

Let's say this is one of the function:

```
/* this code is part of a class */

    template <typename T, typename T_Policy> // Not important but just showing the template parameters of the class

    void Allocate(unsigned int numElements)
    {
      // Some code here
      while (someCondition) // Other functions don't have the loop, this is just an example
      {
        // Some code here

        if (T_Policy::trackElements) { /* some code here */ }
        if (T_Policy::verbose) { /* some code here */ }
        if (T_Policy::customManager) { /* some code here */ }
        /* and a few other policies */
      }
      // Some more code here
    }
```

I would like the lines of code that are using the policies to be compiled out instead of relying on `if` statements. One obvious way is to put the while loop in overloaded functions each taking a dummy object with a specific policy type. But that means a lot of code duplication. Similar approaches with template specialization will result in code duplication as well.

Is there a way to compile out the code without code duplication?

Comment: So you want something like conditional compilation, depending on the value of variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always change code

```
   if (T_Policy::trackElements) { /* some code here */ }
```

into

```
template <bool b>
void trackElementPhase() {
  /* some code here */
}

template <>
void trackElementPhase<false>() {} // empty body

 ... later in the code

     trackElementPhase<T_Policy::track_elements>();
```

Of course `T_Policy::track_elements` has to be compile time constant for this.

However, I wouldn't bother. The compiler is likely clever enough to optimize out code in

```
   if (T_Policy::trackElements) { /* some code here */ }
```

if the condition is compile time constant.

Comment: Excellent, that is exactly what I was looking for. I was thinking of more complicated solutions and didn't think of this simple one at all.

Answer (score 3):

If the values in the policy are const, the compiler can optimize the generate code because it can see which if is always true or always false.

Comment: @Samaursa: this can be confirmed easily enough by looking at disassembly of *optimized* code.  Don't look at the debug build since it might not contain these optimizations.

Answer (score 0):

You can use recursive templates to make a list of policies, which all get applied, e.g.:

```
#include <iostream>
template <typename Policy, typename Next=void>
struct policy_list {
  static void apply() {
    Policy::implement();
    Next::apply();
  }
};

template <typename Policy>
struct policy_list<Policy, void> {
  static void apply() {
    Policy::implement();
  }
};

struct first_policy {
  static void implement() { std::cout << "Policy 1" << std::endl;  }
};

struct second_policy {
  static void implement() { std::cout << "Policy 2" << std::endl; }
};

int main() {
  typedef policy_list<first_policy, policy_list<second_policy> > policy;
  while (1) {
    policy::apply();
  }
}
```

For three policies you would need to change the `typedef` to:

```
typedef policy_list<first_policy, policy_list<second_policy, policy_list<third_policy> > > policy;
```

Then all you need to do is produce the right policy list at compile time. This could be done by an external part of your build system that generates a header file with a `typedef`, or it could be done with either preprocessor or template magic, depending on what exactly dictates what your policies are.

If you have C++11 available you can simplify the `policy_list` somewhat using variadic templates.

Comment: Hmm, could you explain this a bit further (with let's say a type policy added?)

Comment: CORRECTION: my above comment should read: (with let's say a **third** policy added?)

Comment: @Samaursa - I've added an example of a `typedef` for a third policy. Basically it's a recursive list comprised of (head, tail) tuples. You can avoid writing it like that by using variadic templates in C++11 though.

Comment: @anonymous downvoter - care to comment on the downvote? Whilst the answers about optimizing compilerers doing the sensible thing if the expression is known at compile time are useful and correct, there *are* still scenarios where this form is useful.

Comment: Not sure who down-voted and why (I countered it), but the information is very useful and is one of the answers to the question. I read about typelists in `Modern C++` but didn't fully understand them. Now that I know where they can be applied I will be giving it another read.